# Magento - add an option in Category's Custom Design

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, magento-1.7, php

In `Catalog > Manage Categories`
Under `Custom Design` tab, I want to add a new field just below `Apply to Products`.

Upon searching I found a php file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\CategoryController.php
```

but I cannot find where exactly is it creating those tabs `Custom Design` and how is it adding the fields.

Since it is not a good idea to change admin panel files, which class do I need to inherit from to create an extension that adds a field in the edit category ?

I have found it is loading fields in

```
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tab\Design.php
```

and it seems field are defined in database

```
catalog_eav_attribute` table and `eav_attribute table
```

I added a new field in database but no success. How do I build this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that toturial. Hope this help :)

> http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/